# What device (computer) are users on when they connect to my site

Tags: php

I am developing a web site and am trying to make it work on all devices. I also have a page where people can report issues so I can look into them.  However, I was asking for way too much info from them.  I have done a lot of reading and now can determine through PHP their operating system and browser.  But I still need to know what device they are using to connect.  (Like Mac, Dell, HP, iPad.)  I found some stuff on cell phones and tablets but is there any way of getting the info from desktop and laptop computers?  As you may have guessed I'm a rookie just learning this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: No analytics are going to be able to tell you if it is HP vs Dell. (MacOS vs Win, yes that's possible)

Comment: Why does the brand of the computer matter? IE7 on Win XP on a Dell is just as crappy as IE7 on Win XP on an HP. (Let the flame wars begin... ;))

Comment: In what instance do you need to distinguish between an HP and Dell with the same OS, screen resolution, and browser?  What difference does it make, to your website, whether they're on a laptop or desktop?

Comment: @deceze Are you expecting us to take sides about IE7 being crappy? :)

Comment: I guess I have proven how green I am.  As deceze brought up why would I need that information.  I guess I was over thinking this whole issue. Thanks to all of you that helped me out.  I already have the OS and browser info and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to get information about the hardware. Because the Browser sends the informations. You can get the OS, but not more. And over the OS you can draw a conclusion about the hardware like IPad etc.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you can gather from the device comes in the HTTP header USER_AGENT,  As you said for mobile devices this agent is more descriptive, for desktop browser there is very little you can know (browser , operative system and version)

There are some libraries like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) that can help you retrieve more information for mobiles using a large USER_AGENT DB

Answer (score 0):

You can try using platform.js class:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://raw.github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/master/platform.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('you are using ' + platform.description + ' on an ' + (platform.manufacturer || 'unknown vendor') );
</script>
```

I get the following, for instance: "you are using Firefox 25.0 on OS X 10.9 on an unknown vendor"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

   $browser = get_browser(null, true);
   print_r($browser);
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3

Array
(
   [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
   [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
   [parent] => Firefox 0.9
   [platform] => WinXP
   [browser] => Firefox
   [version] => 0.9
   [majorver] => 0
   [minorver] => 9
   [cssversion] => 2
   [frames] => 1
   [iframes] => 1
   [tables] => 1
   [cookies] => 1
   [backgroundsounds] =>
   [vbscript] =>
   [javascript] => 1
   [javaapplets] => 1
   [activexcontrols] =>
   [cdf] =>
   [aol] =>
   [beta] => 1
   [win16] =>
   [crawler] =>
   [stripper] =>
   [wap] =>
   [netclr] =>
)
```